# Rails, devise, bootstrap and simple forms: form fields being outputted as raw html when they contain an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, simple-form

I have a problem with my devise set up with simple forms (and bootstrap). When I enter invalid data into the sign-up form the error displays but the fields with the offending data are being rendered as raw HTML. See image[image]

I suspect it is related to the simple-form initialiser configuration and the way the fields are being wrapped but I have the standard configuration - its the same as several other projects which work fine. I simply can't seem to see where the problem lies and therefore how to debug it. Suggestions please?

EDIT: here is the code for this form....its the standard devise registrations/new partial

```
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <%= bootstrap_devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4><%= t('.sign_up', :default => "Sign up") %></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { role: "form" }) do |f| %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit t('.sign_up', :default => "Sign up"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</div>
```

Comment: can you share your code for this form?

Comment: This is pretty weird, what if you erase the `bootstrap_devise_error_messages` at the beginning of the form? It may have some extra ending tags that causes this raw output. Try to enter unexpected values so you would receive the error messages (with the errors line erased) and see if your output is again raw html as with the error messages displayed.

Comment: I tried that. I uninstall bootstrap devise views with no luck. I reinstalled simple forms (even though this does not use it) and no luck. No clue where the glitch is